# ¿Cómo mapear correctamente en el web.xml?

Tags: java, jsp, login, httpservletresponse

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Java Servlets, JSP y Apache Tomcat v9.0 Server. Ya tengo mi servlet y estoy usando el modelo de diseño DAO para todo el desarrollo. En la creación del login, cuando estoy haciendo la validación del usuario y contraseña, todo se lee correctamente ya que hice un `System.out.println()` que me indica si el login fue correcto o no, sin embargo, mi `response.sendRedirect()` no me manda a la página que quiero, simplemente se sigue viendo el login a pesar de que mi link sí me muestra la ruta que quiero, que en este caso es: "http://localhost:8080/Trax_Web/views/home.jsp" en donde solo tengo un mensaje sencillo:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Trax - Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

He leído que esto puede ser a causa del web.xml, sin embargo ya agregué mi mapeo y no me funciona, el mismo error aparece.

Cabe mencionar que en la estructura de mi proyecto, los .jsp files los estoy poniendo en una carpeta "views" dentro de la carpeta "WEB-INF". Ya intenté sacando los archivos de ahí poniéndolos en la raíz de Web-INF y no me resulta correcto tampoco.

Mis métodos se ven de la siguiente forma:

```
if(loginDao.login(loginModel)) {
    System.out.println("success");
    response.sendRedirect("views/home.jsp");
} else {
    System.out.println("not success");
    response.sendRedirect("views/login.jsp");
}
```

Mi web.xml queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.trax.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Quisiera saber si realmente estoy mal en mi web.xml file o es otra cosa. Se supone que si el usuario no pone su username y password de forma correcta, la página se debe refrescar en el login, de lo contrario se va al home y esto indica que está dentro de la aplicación para poder usarla.

Answer (score 0):

la estructura de tu proyecto debe ser.

```
project
  | --src
       |--packages....
  |---web 
       |--META_INF
       |--WEB_INF
       |-login.jsp
       |-views
          |-home.jps
          |....
```

e intenta cambiando el url-pattern del servlet.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.trax.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```